# Committing everything before doing a pull, why?

Tags: git, git-pull, git-commit

While working in a branch I'll have a few files that I'm changing.  One of my colleagues tells me that he's pushed a change that I should pull to fix an immediate issue.  If I don't commit my changes, git won't let me pull. Even though none of my files I have modified are being updated.

I'm wondering why this is the case and if possible, is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Could you add a bit more information, e.g. have you configured the branch to be rebased or merged on pull?

Comment: You could do `git stash; git pull; git stash pop`

Comment: I have not configured anything.  Just a simple branch and checkout.  I realize I can stash.  I'm wondering if there is something more efficient or something.

Comment: You *have to* stash or commit. You can't pull with a dirty working directory. I'd upvote JoshRagem's comment as an answer.

Comment: Is there a why this is the case or just "that's the way its written to work"?

Comment: You could `git fetch` instead of `git pull`, then later, when you are at a more convenient stage in your own directory (i.e. a clean working directory immediately after a commit), manually run `git merge`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git pull` is essentially a fetch followed by a merge. Merges usually require that the working directory is in a clean state; they do that for your safety:

> **Warning:** Running git merge with uncommitted changes is discouraged: while possible, it leaves you in a state that is hard to back out of in the case of a conflict. ([source](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge))

And:

> If any of the remote changes overlap with local uncommitted changes, the merge will be automatically cancelled and the work tree untouched. It is generally best to get any local changes in working order before pulling or stash them away with git-stash. ([source](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull))

I believe that the check in a pure `git merge` is actually more forgiving than in a `git pull`, so you might want to try fetching first and then merging manually. But it’s always a better idea to stash things away first.